# Dynamically bind items to dropdown using jquery

Tags: jquery

How can i dynamically bind a dropdowncheckbox list to values from the page?
I am using the jquery multiple select plugin from :
http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/#acknowledgements

My jquery version is 1.7.2

I can't get jsfiddle to work with the plugin.
I have had a weird issue where the script src stmt cannot be in the head of the layout page(MVC). So i keep it at the bottom of the layout page like this:

```
</body>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.multiple.select.js"></script>
</html>
```

in View:
Select List:

```
<select id="labTestFilter" name="labTestFilter" multiple="multiple" style="width: 200px;">
    @*the values of the select list will be populated by the javascript function*@
</select>
```

But it should still be same for any list type using jquery.

Here is the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/vnVTx/4/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function bindLabTestFilter() {
        // get the list of unique test names on the page and bind it to the select list control
        var a = $(".labtestname").map(function () { return this.innerHTML; }).get();
        a = jQuery.unique(a);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem:

Select List:

```
<select id="labTestFilter" name="labTestFilter" multiple="multiple" style="width: 200px;">
    @*the values of the select list will be populated by the javascript function*@
</select>
```

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function bindLabTestFilter() {
        // get the list of unique test names on the page and bind it to the select list control
        var a = $(".labtestname").map(function () { return this.innerHTML; }).get();
        a = jQuery.unique(a);
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            $("#labTestFilter").append("<option value=\"" + a[i] + "\">" + a[i] + "</option>");
        }
        //converts the select list into a drop down checklist using jquery.multiple.select plugin
        $('#labTestFilter').multipleSelect();
    });

    $(".ms-drop").click(function () {
        $(function showSelectedValues() {
            alert($(".ms-drop input[type=checkbox]:checked").map(
               function () { return this.value; }).get().join(","));
        });
    });

</script>
```